# Bijective functions between involutions and subset of natural numbers

Tags: functions, permutations, involutions

I have a problem with permutations (involutions): If I have the set
$$S=\{1,2,\dots,26\}$$
how can I find a function $f$ that assigns any $n$ from a subset of the natural numbers (lets call it $N$) a unique involution $\sigma$ of $S$?
Also how can I find a function $g$ that does the inverse, so that $f(g(\sigma))=\sigma$ and $g(f(n))=n$?

Im searching for a method that allows me to compute the involution from $n\in N$ as well as compute $n$ from the involution.

Comment: Permutations or involutions? An involution has to give the identity when applied twice, a general permutation doesn't.

Comment: the next permutation is an involution $\sigma=(1,2)(3,4)(6,7)$ : )... i think that the question is: how many involutions exists in $26$ symbols?

Comment: @Chappers: I mean involution

Comment: @janmarqz: No im not searching the total number of involutions. Im searching a way to assign (calculate) a number to any involution and the other way round. Eg. 0 -> (1,1)(2,2)(3,3)...(id), 1 -> (1,2)(2,1)(3,3)...(1 and 2 swapped) and so forth

Comment: if you want a bijection between a subset $N\subset\Bbb N$ and the involutions of $26$ symbols, you are counting them.

Comment: do you know that $(1,2)(2,1)=id$ ?

Comment: @janmarqz Ok maybe I wasnt proper saying what I want, sorry english is not my mothers tongue :) I dont want to count them, Im searching for two functions f and g. f takes a number and returns a involution of S. g takes a involution of S and returns a number. g(f(n))=n.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to construct such functions in the standard mathematical context. I think your only option is to explicitly find all the involutions and say "Ok, this is involution 1, this is involution 2" and so on.

Comment: ok, meanwhile you rearrange your question, check this http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PermutationInvolution.html

Comment: @OriaGruber thats unfortunate. Anyways thanks for the quick answer :)

Comment: Well, I can give you a bijection, although the set onto which it maps is rather unpleasant to describe...

Comment: @Chappers :) Well I rather thought of a nice compact function...

Comment: @janmarqz I fixed my question, i hope its clear now what I'm searching. Hope for a helpful answer :)

Comment: do you know already how many permutation-involutions over $\{1,2,...,26\}$ are there?

Comment: automatic calculation with the recurrence $a(n+1)=a(n)+na(n-1)$ (from http://oeis.org/A000085) and with $a(0)=1$ and $a(1)=1$ going to give you the total of  $a(26)=532,985,208,200,576$

Comment: @janmarqz yes, thats correct. Thats why I tried to find a solution for smaller sets, but I cant find a pattern that could make up for an algorithm :/

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take permutations of $S'=\{0,1,\dotsc,25\}$ because it's easier on the notation. Let the set of involutions on this set be $J$.

Take the integers in base $26$. Let $\sigma$ be an involution on your set. Define an integer in the following fashion: take
$$ g(\sigma)=\sum_{n=0}^{25} \sigma(n) 26^n $$
This gives you a 26-digit number in base $26$, which uniquely corresponds to the permutation $\sigma$, because different permutations have $\sigma(n)$ different for some $n$, and hence one of the digits in their images under $g$ is different. It's also clear how to extract a permutation from this representation: $\sigma(n)$ is the coefficient of $26^n$.

Okay, that's the easy bit. What is the set we're mapping to? Well, it's the subset of $\{0,1,2,\dotsc,26^{26}-1\}$ where all the digits are different in base $26$, and the $n$th digit is $m$ if and only if the $m$th digit is $n$ (i.e. if we have $n 26^m$ in the above expansion, we also have $m 26^n$) (It's easy to see why since we need $\sigma^2=\text{id.}$ Yeah, it's not a very nice set to describe.

Comment: Thanks! I will think about that tomorrow, good night :)